# CSS3 :after Overriding :last-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following CSS to style a simple list:

```
ul.menu_list li {
display: inline;
}
ul.menu_list li:after {
content:" | ";
}
ul.menu_list li:last-child  {
content:"";
}

<ul class="menu_list">
  <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

I get the desired effect except for the last-child is not losing it's vertical bar, " | ".

```
Link | Link | Link |
```

I've tried combining :after:last-child & vice-versa but the first :after declaration always takes precedence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do:

```
ul.menu_list li:after {
    content:" | ";
}
ul.menu_list li:last-child:after  {
    content:"";
}
```

Comment: I tried this and I swear it didn't work but it certainly is. Guess I need a break. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
ul.menu_list li:not(:last-child):after {
  content:" | ";
}
```

Comment: Works great. I didn't know about the "not()" functionality. Nice and streamlined this way.

Comment: @timdream Yes, see [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t37). Should be supported in nearly everything except < IE9.

Answer (score 0):

`ul.menu_list li:last-child:after` should do the trick.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_ajm/REfnX/) that shows it in action..

Answer (score 0):

I found "li+li:before" works in IE8, Chrome, FireFox and Safari for Windows

Comment: e.g., li+li:before{content: '\0020 \2215 \0020';}